# Eclipse can't find my project in folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project, loading

I've got a source code from a friend, and I want to modify it, when I click 
new project => android project from existing code => Browse (selected the dir)

eclipse can't find any project, there's no project check box to check and press continue , 
while I can see it does work at my friend pc, other people computers , etc ...

Thanks

Comment: Did you only get the source code? Eclipse looks for a `.project` file.

Comment: I've got "src" folder, .project file , and ".settings" folder

Comment: What you could try instead is doing an import. Right-click your `Project Explorer` and select `Import...`, then `Existing Project into Workspace` and browse to that directory.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the whole eclipse project.  Try my answer, just past the source into a new project.

Comment: @AliAl-Zubidy - `.classpath` file may be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sotirios said, eclipse will look for a .project file to determine whether a project is located in that location.

If you were given just the source, you could try just pasting all the source into a new android project, but if dependencies are complex it may cause you issues.

Comment: Thanks , this worked, I've created a new project and got the src files from the old one

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad to hear it.